# Controlling Terminal Services Session w/ elevated rights

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, terminal-server

I would imagine that this question is really quite stupid, but I have to ask.

I need to reset a mail profile on my terminal server. The problem is that the admin who set up the terminal server restricted access to the control panel (and mail utility). This presents a bit of a problem as far as resetting this profile is concerned. If I try to right click on Outlook and go to the Properties option, I get a message that it's restricted.

I've tried logging into the server as admin and then taking over the remote session with Terminal Services manager, but it looks as though when I do that my rights are the same as the users.

Is there a way I can get access to the mail icon (or any other program for that matter) if I have the domain admin credentials on an RDC connection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about talking to the Admin and explaining your need...

Comment: In a perfect world, the admin would respond to my inquiries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the way I've always done this is by removing the lock down policy for the user.

Choose the *Policy* > Go to the *Delegation* Tab > *Advanced*.

Add the user and choose *Deny* for *Apply Policy*. Have the user log back in and they can change it.

Then remove them from *Advanced* and log them out.